# Overlay above flyout by ProgressRing (UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I am hiding all the controls when using ProgressRing (the loading circle) as shown (see image). The project is written on the Blank App (Universal Windows Platform). How do I dim all the controls while the ProgressRing is shown.

[controls showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rZWe.png)

[controls dimmed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAXib.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dim all the controls, you can put a layer in your current page which is invisible and add the ProgressRing in it. When you want to display your ProgressRing, the set the layer as visible. For example, I added a Grid as a layer which Opacity is 0.4.

.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="MyBorder" Background="Black" Visibility="Collapsed"  Opacity="0.4">
        <ProgressRing IsActive="True" Height="100" Width="100" x:Name="MyRing"/>
    </Grid>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="hello"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="world" ></TextBlock>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">show progress</Button>
        <Image Source="Assets/StoreLogo.png" Width="400" Height="400"></Image>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

.cs:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    MyBorder.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: I can medium opacity and not allowed to click into zeno ?

Comment: What does "I can medium opacity and not allowed to click into zeno" mean? Can you show more details about your expected behavior?

Comment: I want the button to dim and can't work anymore, on click button ?

Comment: Do you mean after you click the button and want the button to be dim, then can't be clicked at all? You can try to use `Button.IsEnabled = false;` method, is this the effect you want?